# Is there a way to run SSJS as async?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

We need to make thousands of API calls to 3rd party server.
I was planning to do so using script activity in the automation studio.
But, since SSJS and AMPScript are synchronous this can take hours and even days.

Is there a way to make the API functions execute asynchronous?
That way I can loop and not get a timeout.